# Convert query using VALUES instead IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-9.3

I have following SQL query

```
UPDATE user
SET processing = 1
WHERE
    ID IN (
        SELECT
            ID
        FROM
            user
        WHERE
            processing =0
        LIMIT 3000 FOR UPDATE
    ) RETURNING *
```

I'm trying to optimize it following this [thread](https://www.datadoghq.com/2013/08/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/)

```
UPDATE user
SET processing = 1
WHERE
    ID = ANY (ARRAY ( 
        SELECT
            ID
        FROM
            user
        WHERE
            processing =0
        LIMIT 3000 FOR UPDATE
    )) RETURNING *
```

and it works fine.

Now i'd like to test also [VALUES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-values.html) but i have not found a correct way to do it...
Someone know how to do? I have tested using string_agg but doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work". Show the query you tried and the resulting error please.

Comment: The `values` row constructor is used to create *static* data. I don't see how this applies in your case as your using a query to get the list of values.

Comment: @CraigRinger i dont' know which is best way. I have tried with string_agg but it doesn't work i want to mean 'i don't know if is right approach'.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i can't make static this data after select?

Answer (score 1):

A `VALUES` clause is not useful here. As @a_horse_with_no_name comments, it's only for static (literal) data. You're using a query to produce the data on demand.

`IN` should be converted to `= ANY` by the optimizer; I wouldn't expect any difference at all.

In both cases you're searching a 3000 element array. That's not going to be wonderfully efficient for high row counts. I'd usually use a join on a subquery in `FROM` instead.

```
UPDATE user
SET processing = 1
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ID
    FROM
        user
    WHERE
        processing = 0
    LIMIT 3000 FOR UPDATE
) l
WHERE l.id = user.id
RETURNING *
```

(untested).

That won't fix the underlying issues with your query's logic though.

- You don't specify any `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. So you'll get whatever rows the server decides to give you, in any possible order. If *any* row is already locked then the query will block and retry.
- `FOR UPDATE` is applied *after* the `LIMIT` clause. This means that if rows are locked, when the query retries after blocking, if it selected the same set of rows as the query it was waiting for it'll eliminate all rows when it re-checks the `WHERE` clause (because `processing` is now set to `1`). So it'll return zero rows not the expected 3000, or at least less than 3000.

Anyway: it looks like you are attempting to write a task queuing system. Do not do this. You *will* get it wrong - at least if you care about crash safety, guaranteeing to run tasks exactly once, etc. Hopefully you will get it wrong by producing a concurrent/parallel task queuing system that only ever hands out one chunk of tasks at a time, so it has no actual parallelism. If you're unlucky you'll instead get it wrong by producing a task queuing system that loses tasks, reports them complete when they aren't, fails to retry failed tasks, etc.

Use an existing task queuing system - look into Celery as one option.

BTW, there's a patch for PostgreSQL 9.5 to add support for `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` that'll make writing a real concurrent task queue easy in plain SQL. It won't make 9.4, so it's not going to be available in a hurry.